# R horizontal barplot with aligned plot ontop

Tags: r, graphics, plot, bar-chart

I am having trouble getting the spacing right on a plot on top of a horizontal barplot. It is the same general issue as described here: 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-lines-or-points-to-an-existing-barplot/

But I am trying to use "plot" instead of "points" or "lines". Is there a trick for using plot to get the spacing of the bars and the points to match?

[image: Misaligned points and bars example]

Code:

```
barplot(df$DIC_mM,col=scalegreen, xlab="DIC mM", horiz=TRUE, xlim=c(0,0.7), 
         col.axis="white", col.lab="white", axes=FALSE, border="white")
axis(1,line=1,col="white",col.ticks="white",col.axis="white")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(df$d13DIC,df$Order, type="p", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab ="",
      col="deepskyblue2", lwd=5, xlim=c(-50,170), lend=2, col.lab="white", ylab="")
axis(3,at = c(-50,0,50,100,150), line=1, col="deepskyblue2", col.ticks="deepskyblue2", 
      col.axis="deepskyblue2")
mtext(expression(paste(delta ^{13},'DIC'," \u0028","\u2030","\u0029")), 3, 
       line=-0.5,at=50,col="deepskyblue2", cex=0.75)
```

Comment: Read here how you can control the width and the space between bars, https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html

Comment: Or use rect() for plot bars on the same scale that scatter plot

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22341228/496488) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use `points` to add the points? If you're willing to use `points` you can do it like this:

Create barplot and save the y-coordinates of the bars to `y`. You haven't provided sample data, so I'll use the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
y = barplot(mtcars$mpg[1:10], horiz=TRUE)
```

Now add the points. We use `y` as the y values, because those are the coordinates of the midpoints of each bar:

```
points(sqrt(mtcars$mpg[11:20]), y, col="red", pch=16, cex=2)
```

[image]

When you use `par(new=TRUE)` and then call `plot` again, you're overlaying a new plot with a new coordinate system that in general will be different from the original coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked, based on this post suggested by  eipi10: [midpoints returned by barplot function do not actually line up with midpoints of bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341019/midpoints-returned-by-barplot-function-do-not-actually-line-up-with-midpoints-of/22341228#22341228)

> mp<-barplot(df$DIC_mM,col=scalegreen, xlab="DIC mM", horiz=TRUE, xlim=c(0,0.7), col.axis="white", col.lab="white", axes=FALSE, border="white", ylim=c(0,length(df$DIC_mM)+2))
>   axis(1,line=1,col="white",col.ticks="white",col.axis="white")
>   par(new = TRUE)
>   plot(df$d13DIC, mp, type="p", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab ="",col="deepskyblue2", lwd=5, xlim=c(-50,170), lend=2, col.lab="white", ylab="", ylim=c(0,length(df$DIC_mM)+2))
>   axis(3,at = c(-50,0,50,100,150),line=1,col="deepskyblue2",col.ticks="deepskyblue2",col.axis="deepskyblue2")
>   mtext(expression(paste(delta ^{13},'DIC'," \u0028","\u2030","\u0029")),3,line=-0.5,at=50,col="deepskyblue2", cex=0.75)